# KATEX : How to Handle KaTex Parse Error in Try-Catch block?

Tags: web, katex

We are currently using auto-render extension for rendering KaTeX into preview mode, we do have helper function which calls `renderMathInElement` function and our helper function is as follows:

```
function renderMath(element) {
            try {
                window.renderMathInElement(element,
                {
                    delimiters: [
                        { left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true },
                        { left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true },
                        { left: "$", right: "$", display: true },
                        { left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false }
                    ]
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
```

This function does not catch any error thrown by KaTeX. Can someone point, what and where we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-renderer does not throw parse exceptions, it [catches them](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/29fc2d56d409aaf5875601dc57da2cf66d1577e2/contrib/auto-render/auto-render.js#L36-L44) and prints them to `console.error`.